# WordPress contact form 7 redirection

Tags: wordpress

I want redirect contact us form 7 , for different pages, 
I have multiple custom posts, and I want that when the user wants to read this, then first fill a form, and then redirect to full page. I want this process for every single post.

My test case can be seen [here](http://polestarllp.com/case-study/).

I am doing this:

```
on_sent_ok: "location.replace('http://polestarllp.com/casestudy/benefits-of-sql-on-hadoop/');"
```

But this is for only one page.

Comment: I think this is working fine

Comment: rajkumar i nedd this for every post, when i submit form then form is redirect on same post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For redirecting your contact form after submission . This is perfect method ,

```
on_sent_ok: "location.replace('http://polestarllp.com/casestudy/benefits-of-sql-on-hadoop/');"
```

But if you getting any issue then you can use redirection addon for contact us plugin .may be these link help you.

1:https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/redirect-cf7/

2:https://github.com/anup04sust/Contact-Form-7-Redirect/blob/master/contact-form-7-redirect.php

3:https://github.com/kasparsd/contact-form-7-extras/blob/master/plugin.php

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn’t work, check if Ajax is correctly working on your site. 
follow this link 
http://contactform7.com/redirecting-to-another-url-after-submissions/

Answer (score 0):

you need to call post id instead of this link  ('http://polestarllp.com/casestudy/benefits-of-sql-on-hadoop/')

```
on_sent_ok: "location.replace('<a href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '"');"
```

hope it will work for you

Comment: it's not working can you give me exact format of this code

Comment: this is not working with contact form 7 advance functionality

Comment: wehn try this on_sent_ok: "location.replace('<?php echo get_permalink( $post->ID ); ?>');" getting page not fount error